# How to link to a file in twig template

Tags: views, theming, uri

I'm trying to link to a file in a view.
I have a field in the view that outputs the link if I use it like this:

```
<div class="product-cta-view-pdf">
  {{ fields.field_notice.content }}
</div>
```

The output: /sites/default/files/products/notice/test.pdf

What I want to do is use that to create a link to the pdf to view (and another one to download).
How can I use this in the href of a link?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the drupal build in file_url twig function for that:

```
{{ file_url( fields.field_notice.content) }}
```

You can find more information about the Drupal build in twig functions here:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/functions-in-twig-templates

Comment: this opens the pdf viewer but doesn't show any content.. it just keeps loading

Comment: As it opens a pdf viewer, your browser seems to know it is about a pdf. It sounds that the link is correct. What is the html output between the <div class="product-cta-view-pdf"> and </div>? If you follow that link manually does it work? If not you probably have a corrupted file.

Comment: it outputs: <a href="#pdf" class="product-brochure-link">Voir notice</a>

Comment: Ok so it seems that the output was not just the link in plain text in html output. I have to guess a little now, but try the following: {{ file_url( fields.field_notice.uri.value) }}  If that doesnt work, try inspecting the variable for the correct link: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/discovering-and-inspecting-variables-in-twig-templates

Comment: When I try it with .uri.value, I get "/" as href. And if I try to dump anything, it crashes